# Input File Reading Just Repeats First Data Line from 1 of 2 Files

Tags: c++, debugging, input, data-files

I'm working on a project. The idea is that it has two input files, we'll call them `TimeFile` and `FullFile`.

`TimeFile` gives two timestamps in the format:

```
DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS     DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS
```

And `FullFile` is in the format of a timestamp and some data:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS   Value    Error    Error
```

The idea is that the program reads the timestamps from `TimeFile`, then goes through all the lines in `FullFile`, and if it finds a timestamp from `FullFile` that lands between two from `TimeFile`, it copies the whole line into a new smaller data file. In essence, I want to go from one gigantic data file to a bunch of smaller data files divided up by time intervals.

Needless to say, it doesn't work. It does most of what I want, but the resulting smaller data files are always empty.

The strange part is why. It appears to read the timestamps from `TimeFile` just fine, but it screws up reading from `FullFile` and just reads the first line over and over again. I don't really have a solid idea why either, best I can determine is that they're reading the same way, but one works and the other doesn't.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  //Read Run-Times-File - Cycle 1
  std::ifstream TimeFile;
  TimeFile.open("jet_run_times.dat");
  if(!TimeFile.good()){
    std::cout << "TimeFile Didn't Work" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
    
  //Read Full-File - Cycle 2
  std::ifstream FullFile;
  FullFile.open("jet_full.txt");
  if(!FullFile.good()){
    std::cout << "FullFile Didn't Work" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << "Both Files Worked" << std::endl;

  std::ofstream results; 
  
  //Initial Time - A ; Final Time - B ; Jet Pressure Time - C

  int iday, ihour, imin, isec, fday, fhour, fmin, fsec, imon, fmon;
  char dash, colon ;
  std::string imonth, fmonth ;
  //std::ostringstream temp;
  int run = 0;
  int year, month, day , hour, min;
  double sec, value, neg, pos, AfterStart, BeforeEnd;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < 192 ; i++) {
  //Cycle 1
  //Write jet_run_XXX.txt
    run++;
  
    std::ostringstream temp;
  
    if(run <= 9) temp << "jet_run_00" << run << ".txt" ;
    if( (run >= 10) && (run <= 99) ) temp << "jet_run_0" << run << ".txt" ;
    if(run >= 100) temp << "jet_run_" << run << ".txt" ;
    results.open(temp.str());
    std::cout << temp.str() << " File Made" << std::endl;
    
    TimeFile >> iday >> dash >> imonth  >> ihour >> colon >> imin >> colon >> isec  >> fday >> dash >> fmonth >> fhour >> colon >> fmin >> colon >> fsec;

    /*
    std::cout << "iday " << iday << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dash " << dash << std::endl;
    std::cout << "imonth " << imonth << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ihour " << ihour << std::endl;
    std::cout << "colon " << colon << std::endl;
    std::cout << "imin " << imin << std::endl;
    std::cout << "isec " << isec << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fday " << fday << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dash " << dash << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fmonth " << fmonth << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fhour " << fhour << std::endl;
    std::cout << "colon " << colon << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fmin " << fmin << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fsec " << fsec << std::endl;
    */

    if( imonth == "Apr-22") imon = 4;
    if( fmonth == "Apr-22") fmon = 4;
    if( imonth == "May-22") imon = 5;
    if( fmonth == "May-22") fmon = 5;
    
  /* 
     std::cout << "imon " << imon << std::endl;
     std::cout << "fmon " << fmon << std::endl;
  */

  //Cycle 2
    
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 5833 ; j++){

      FullFile >> year >> dash >> month >> dash >> day >> hour >> colon >> min >> colon >> sec >> value >> neg >> pos;
      std::cout << j << std::endl; 
      
      /*    
    std::cout << "year " << year << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dash " << dash << std::endl;
    std::cout << "month " << month << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dash " << dash << std::endl;
    std::cout << "day " << day << std::endl;
    std::cout << "hour " << hour << std::endl;
    std::cout << "colon " << colon << std::endl;
    std::cout << "min " << min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sec " << sec << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value " << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "neg " << neg << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pos " << pos << std::endl;  
      */

  //Set-Up the Check if  A <= C <= B
      AfterStart = (sec - isec) + (min - imin)*100 + (hour - ihour)*10000 + (day - iday)*1000000 + (month - imon)*100000000;   
      BeforeEnd = (fsec - sec) + (fmin - min)*100 + (fhour - hour)*10000 + (fday - day)*1000000 + (fmon - month)*100000000;

      std::cout << "AfterStart " << AfterStart << std::endl;
      std::cout << "BeforeEnd " << BeforeEnd << std::endl;

  //If A <= C <= B, copy all of C to jet_run_XXX.txt
      if ( (AfterStart >= 0.0) && (BeforeEnd >= 0.0) ){
    results << year << dash << month << dash << day << "  " << hour << colon << min << colon << sec << "  " << value << "  " << pos << "  " << neg << '\n' <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << "Got One!" << std::endl;
      }
    }
    //End Cycle 2
    results.close();
  }

  //End Cycle 1
  return 0;
}
```

I'm stumped, any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit:** Thinking it might help if I give a few lines of each of my data files to see if it's a formatting issue, so here's the first 3 lines of each:

TimeFile

```
03-Apr-22 22:42:19  03-Apr-22 22:56:13
03-Apr-22 22:58:25  03-Apr-22 23:15:14
03-Apr-22 23:17:23  03-Apr-22 23:35:32
```

FullFile

```
2022-04-13 12:39:37.500000000   70.00000    0.0 0.0
2022-04-13 12:43:52.500000000   70.00000    0.0 0.0
2022-04-13 12:48:07.500000000   70.00000    0.0 0.0
```

Edit2:- Important discovery. Running this code with that block uncommented out reproduces the data in the line but instead of 70 0 0 you get 1 0 43.1495 for the last three values. GetLine doesn't seem to do this but I'm having trouble understanding how to cut that open.

Not entirely sure what this means beyond that *somehow* that's not reading those values properly but when I try to account for a tab it's not an improvement.

Comment: You should always check the result from input operations. `if (FullFile >> year >> dash >> month >> dash >> day >> hour >> colon >> min >> colon >> sec >> value >> neg >> pos) { /* process data */ } else { /* handle error */ }` An undetected error reading is a common reason for data to repeat.

Comment: Thought I did, that's what the block of commented out code below that reading is for, and it was working fine when it was in.

Comment: Well, if you read all 192 lines worth of data and manually matched them up to the input then I suppose you don't have a problem, but wouldn't it be easier to let the code tell you there was a problem? Gets a little harder when there's 5833 lines to manually check doesn't it?

Comment: And because you got me thinking I checked it again, and when I uncomment it I do see repeating. The values are all correct for the first line but it just repeats it. Alright, that helps but still trying to think of how to fix it.

Comment: Alright, just did a test with it repeating and displaying whole lines and that appears to work correctly. So maybe there's an invisible character at the end of the line that isn't working?